# How do I read PCM audio from a file?

Tags: software-development, audio

I would then to write the PCM data directly to the I<sup>2</sup>S interface.

Is there an existing API that would allow me to read an audio file and get at the PCM digital data?

Comment: What format? e.g. for uncompressed 16-bit mono WAVs, skip the first 44 bytes then feed the rest out the interface verbatim...

Comment: I was thinking 16 bit stereo WAV, is that feasible?

Comment: At first glance this question doesn't look like it's quite on-topic for the site.  Could someone explain  its application to Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @jandjorgensen - There's a lot of interest in utilising the Pi in audio projects, hopefully there will be many more questions tagged [tag:audio] and attracting at least some of that community here would be a good thing, so don't scare them away :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379353/what-is-a-lightweight-cross-platform-wav-playing-library) SO question; [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) seems to be favourite.